# Little endian and big endian assignment

Tags: c, endianness

I have the following piece of code

```
int i = 321;
char ch = i;
printf("%d", ch);
```

`i` in binary is `00000000 00000000 00000001 01000001` and the output is `65`. 
From the above code, I understand that since `char` takes only 1 byte of memory, the first 3 bytes of `i` are dropped and the last byte is assigned to `ch`. Hence the result.

My machine is little-endian. Is the result in `ch` based on the endianness of the underlying machine? Please clarify.

Comment: unless you use pointer arithmetics, the c runtime library should abstract away from endianness. The narrowing of int to char effectively is a modulo operation and iirc is defined this way in the standard ( better look up, though ...)

Comment: So, the direct answer is: No, this result hasnüt to do anything with endianess.

Comment: If default `char` is a signed data type in your environment (which is more common than not) then the behavior associated with assigning an out-of-range value to a `char` variable is *undefined*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: _Conversion_ is implementation-defined (see User36740's answer), overflow (and generating trap representations, if any) is undefined.

Comment: @mafso: quite right, my bad.  As I commented also on that answer, though, the behavior defined by a given implementation is unrestricted, so it *could* reflect the endianness of the representation of `int` (and / or `char`, if applicable).

Answer (score 7):

Quoting C11, 6.3.1.3:

> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
> other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
> is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is
> converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the
> maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value
> is in the range of the new type.
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be
> represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
> implementation-defined signal is raised.

Standard talks only about values. So if char is unsigned: 321-256=65. If char is signed, behavior is implementation defined.

Comment: Where "implementation defined" *could* reflect the endianness of the underlying representation.

Comment: @user36740 char is signed in my case and the value of ch is 65. Can you tell me what you meant by 'implementation defined'?

Comment: In the rather theoretical situation where signed chars are not represented by twos complement, you might very well get some other value. But I am not aware of any machine doing that in our corner of the galaxy.

Comment: Implementation-defined means different compilers may react differently. You have to consult documentation of your compiler / architecture.

In practice, this means that it is harder to write portable code.

Comment: @PoojaNBabu: It means, that an implementation may define it in any way it pleases, but has to document the choice made and stick to it consistently. For GCC, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html#toc_C-Implementation) under 4.5. This is by far the most common way to define things in this case (you can almost rely on it, I think).

Comment: "Implementation defined" means the C standard does not dictate the behavior, but requires implementations (roughly, "compilers") to define the behavior and ensure that they produce that behavior.  Different compilers may define the behavior differently.  It is not necessarily a function of their representation of `char` values.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your answer is not endian dependent. Your compiler will ensure that the least significant byte is copied across irrespective of endianness.

```
int i = 232;
int *p_i = &i;
char* pc_i = (char*)p_i;
printf("%d", (int)(*pc_i));
```

Will give the correct answer on little-endian architectures but the wrong answer on big-endian architectures. (type punning to char* does not violate strict aliasing rule)

Comment: Your `printf()` is wrong.  It appears you want `printf("%d", (int) *pc_i)`, or possiibly `printf("%c", *pc_i)`.  For sure you must dereference the pointer, and you cannot safely do without the cast in the `"%d"` variant because you don't know whether `char` is a signed type.

Answer (score 1):

No, the result in `ch` is not based on the endianness of the underlying machine.

C does not have any concept of endianness AFAIK.  `char ch = i` is equivalent to `char ch = i % CHAR_MAX`.

If you did want to peek at the last or first byte of `i`, you could do this...

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  // INT_MAX = 01111111111111111111111111111
  int i = INT_MAX;

  unsigned char * front = &i;

  // This assumes ints are 4 bytes long, not a safe assumption!
  unsigned char * back = front + 3;

  printf ("%d %d", *front, *back);
  // Prints 255 127.  My machine is little-endian.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code will work the same on all sorts of machines. The int value cast down to a char will leave you with the bits of i which fit into  ch.

In order to see the endian-ness of your machine, you would have to recast pointers pointing to your int.

```
int i = 321;
char ch = *((char *)&i);
```

Or use unions in clever ways. You can even produce access violations with that stuff if your machine is picky about alignment...

```
union Foo { int i; char c; } foo; foo.i = 321; char ch = foo.c;
```

Comment: No, the code produces *implementation-defined behavior* in any of the many C environments where default `char` is a *signed*, 8-bit type.  The code is not required to work the same from one such machine to another.

Comment: I was not saying this code would have any properties other than showing ways how you can make your machines endianess matter. I did not even issue a theory on how those differences would manifest themselves. The code snippets are intended to contrast the code in original post, which is not affected by endianess.